# In what order should I read the Touhou Project manga?

Tags: touhou-project

After a little online search, I've found the following list, compiled from [wikia](http://touhou.wikia.com/wiki/Comics#Official_.28Japanese.29) and [wiki](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Official_Literature#Comics) (excluding the two short stories and including the two comics in the Artbooks section), of official Touhou Project manga related to ZUN's scenarios:

- [Eastern and Little Nature Deity](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Eastern_and_Little_Nature_Deity)
- [Strange and Bright Nature Deity](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Strange_and_Bright_Nature_Deity)
- [Oriental Sacred Place](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Oriental_Sacred_Place)
- [Extra of the Wind](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Extra_of_the_Wind)
- [Memorizable Gensokyo](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Memorizable_Gensokyo)
- [Silent Sinner in Blue](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Silent_Sinner_in_Blue)
- [Inaba of the Moon and Inaba of the Earth](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Inaba_of_the_Moon_and_Inaba_of_the_Earth)
- [Wild and Horned Hermit](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Wild_and_Horned_Hermit)
- [Forbidden Scrollery](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Forbidden_Scrollery)

In what order should I start reading these manga?

Comment: I've edited your question to include only the official manga, as fan comics of Touhou, as one might expect, are too numerous to list.

Answer (score 2):

I heavily recommend reading the manga in release order, taking into consideration the release dates and plots of the official games. Most of the manga are standalone (with some exceptions) in the same way that the games are standalone to an extent, but keeping everything in line with game release dates will allow for better understanding of the plot context.

Note that the manga focusing on the three fairies are directly associated with the Great Fairy Wars game, and note that Kasen did not have her first appearance in a game until WaHH had been going on for quite a while.

In general however, feel free to read them in any order (aside from the ones that are direct sequels, etc). Inaba of the Moon and Inaba of the Earth for example is entirely made up of separate comics, and as long as you are familiar with the dynamic of the characters, it is an enjoyable experience.

Comment: I recommend reading the fairy saga manga while listening the CD music of them and then proceed to play Fairy Wars 12.8

Comment: Good point on the music. Definitely read with the music - that goes for the other manga with music tracks as well (SSiB and some others I think?)

Answer (score 1):

In any way you like each stories revolve around individual incidents, there is no particular order to them, but if you really care about the time chronology.. I think its almost correct with exception of Wild and Horned Hermit events taking longer than Forbidden Scrollery, you must understand that most of the Fairies manga, Forbidden Scrollery and Wild and Horned hermit as well as Visionary fairies in a shrine happen in between at the same time line, these comics aren't sequels but rather concentrate on different view points and characters and are complementary both to themselves and the games but also concentrate on exclusive plot lines that nevertheless are cannon through them all, so there is no particular order for you to read them and is more like whose story you are interested in at the moment.